# Why my electro magnet isn't working

Tags: electromagnetic

[image: pp]

Hello I study at middle school.

My school project is doing an electromagnet.

I charge a capacitor with 450V 330uF and I created a coil with copper wire.

When I press the button there is a spark inside button but the magnet doesn't work.

Please help.

Comment: This is not how you make an electromagnet. The magnetic field is created inside the coil. Not inside of the *wrapped* coil. Also I don't see what the function of the capacitor here. It will give you only a momentary power.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+make+a+solenoid

Comment: Hmm, also if that cap is fully charged its potentially deadly.. be careful..

Comment: And what do you mean by "not working"? Do you expect the ball bearing to lift up? That's not how it works.

Comment: As it is now you have a net effect of 2½ turns in the direction I believe you care about.

Comment: You effectively have only about 3-4 turns in that coil and it will attract the steel towards the coil (a bit). You might see the loose coil move upwards momentarily. You might see it compress slightly. You are not being nice to the capacitor and could damage it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there are billions of answers on the Internet, we don't need to become the billionth and one. OP should do some better research.

Comment: @HarrySvensson - Chiil out, would you? OP has identified as a middle school student, so cut her some slack.

Comment: [Here are more pictures on how to wind an electromagnet](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+wind+an+electro+magnet&client=firefox-b&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiy5q-i3draAhXkIsAKHVYJCTIQ_AUICygC&biw=1254&bih=902) than is possible to absorb in an hour. How you managed to come up with this idea beats me. Just google "how to wind an electro magnet" and look at the images.

Comment: **IF** you are really doing what you say & show then you should STOP NOW. The arrangement that you have is lethally dangerous. It could easily kill you or someone else. Are you REALLY charging the cap to 450V. From what source? Using what circuit. The breadboard you are using to connect components is not rated for the voltage or current that you will experience.  MUCH more detail needed. AND look at the links that people have provided to what a solenoid should look like.

Comment: Maybe you should first learn what you are doing and then try with a battery, coil and an iron nail.

Comment: @HelenLux - I admire your willingness to go full out and juice up a concept, but you really need to back off. A bug zapper puts out thousands of volts. Your capacitor won't handle it, and your switch isn't rated for it either, so you're taking your life in your hands (pretty much literally) every time you push the button. Please back off and start with something like a 6 or 12 volt battery. You won't get the sort of drama I think you're hoping for, but drama is not always a good thing. Please read Kipling's "The Secret of the Machinery" - "We can neither love nor pity nor forgive."

Comment: Expanding WhatRoughBeat's point: Kipling wrote:
"We can neither love nor pity nor forgive.   If you make a slip in handling us you die!" That capacitor can easily kill you if you let it when charged to even quite a lot less than its rated value.   || [**" The Secret of the Machines" - Rudyard Kipling"**](https://www.poetryloverspage.com/poets/kipling/secret_of_machinery.html) :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**IF** you are really doing what you say & show then you should STOP NOW before you kill yourself or somebody else.

The arrangement that you have is lethally dangerous.
It could **easily** kill you or someone else.

Are you REALLY charging the cap to 450V.
From what source?
Using what circuit.

The breadboard you are using to connect components is not rated for the voltage or current that you will experience.
MUCH more detail needed. AND look at the links that people have provided to what a solenoid should look like.

As  Andy Aka said - an electromagnet should look something like [these](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+wind+an+electro+magnet&client=firefox-b&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiy5q-i3draAhXkIsAKHVYJCTIQ_AUICygC&biw=1254&bih=902).

[Many ideas](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b&biw=1680&bih=919&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=cz_jWo3rDoP58gWFlqj4Bg&q=diy+electromagnet&oq=diy+electromagnet&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0l5j0i30k1j0i8i30k1l2j0i24k1l2.213982.219628.0.220683.6.6.0.0.0.0.366.1544.2-5j1.6.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.2.584...0i13k1j0i13i30k1j0i8i13i30k1.0.8o21sFBdG4I)